# How can I train GPT-3 (or similar) to search for answers my text file

Tags: gpt-3

My company has large sets of standards that are quite dry to read through and find answers to questions.  How can I have an AI perform the search?

The text files are too long to submit with every query, so it seems like I would need to train the model with the data.  What's the simplest solution out there?

Comment: there is a variant of BERT which is specifically trained to answer questions given text data. more specifically, it was trained to return $start$ and $end$ indexes that should in theory mark the answer in the text that corresponds to the question. Might have to fine-tune it a bit by giving it your specific data, I would start of with few-shot (before transfer learning for example)